# Google Speech API unable to find a file on Google Storage: error 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

I am trying to convert audio clips [.flac format] to text using the google cloud speech api.I am using the python client library for making requests and  have a bucket on the GCP with a flat directory structure which is used to store the audio files and make asynchronous requests.Below is the python code for making requests

```
            from google.cloud import storage
            from google.cloud import speech
            from google.cloud.speech import enums
            from google.cloud.speech import types
            import json

            def AudioAnalyze(bucket_name):
                storage_client = storage.Client()
                speech_client = speech.SpeechClient()
                bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
                bucket_contents = bucket.list_blobs()
                urls = []
                audio_content=[]
                for i in bucket_contents:
                        urls.append("gs://"+i.bucket.name+"/"+i.public_url.split("/")[-1])
                for gcs_uri in urls:
                    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
                    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
                    encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
                    sample_rate_hertz=44100,
                    language_code='en-US')
                    operation = speech_client.long_running_recognize(config,audio)
                    print(gcs_uri)
                    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
                    response = operation.result(timeout=450)
                    speech2text=[]
                    for result in response.results:
                        for alternative in result.alternatives:
                            speech2text.append(alternative.transcript)
                    ad_content=" ".join(speech2text)
                    audio_content.append(ad_content)
                with open("path/to a/json file/file.json","w") as f:
                    json.dump(audio_content,f)


            if __name__=="__main__":
                    AudioAnalyze("adsaudiocontent")
```

I am encountering an error: **google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Requested entity was not found** on a particular file present in the bucket while all the other files are being processed properly.The audio files have gone through a similar processing pipeline.The audio files are **available on my public bucket:adsaudiocontent** so that you can replicate the error.For Additional details here is the traceback.

```
                Traceback (most recent call last):
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 54, in error_remapped_callable
                    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 487, in __call__
                    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 437, in _end_unary_response_blocking
                    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
                grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, Requested entity was not found.)>
                The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
                Traceback (most recent call last):
                  File "audioanalyze.py", line 40, in <module>
                    AudioAnalyze("adsaudiocontent")
                  File "audioanalyze.py", line 25, in AudioAnalyze
                    operation = speech_client.long_running_recognize(config,audio)
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/gapic/speech_client.py", line 264, in long_running_recognize
                    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 139, in __call__
                    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
                    on_error=on_error,
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
                    return target()
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 206, in func_with_timeout
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                  File "/home/pythonuser1/.virtualenvs/virtual_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 56, in error_remapped_callable
                    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
                  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
                google.api_core.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Requested entity was not found.
```

Comment: I am not able to apply read privileges to the adsaudiocontent bucket without providing admin privileges.The Storage object viewer policy is not working..[I guess this is a question for another post ].Please provide me your gmail id so that I can provide access to the bucket.

Comment: `i.public_url.split("/")[-1]` seems like a bad idea. Any object names that contain a '/' character will have most of their name stripped out. Why not just `i.name`?

Comment: Thanks a ton Brandon - Looks like the issue was with how I was creating the filenames. I was unaware about the .name attribute. It works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accidentally chopping part of the URL erroneously  with the "/" matching, which probably resulted in this error.

The bucket name from the class [bucket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/storage/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py) can be used directly.